# Show user's username, name, surname and when they were last logged in

Tags: bash, awk

so basically I need to get username, name and surname of users with name given as a parameter and when they were last logged in. Main issue with my current code is that `lastlog` shows only headline and no real data. Any ideas how to fix that?

`awk -F ":" -v nam="$Var" '$5 ~ nam {("lastlog -u" $1 | getline tmp); print $1,$5,tmp}' OFS='\t' /etc/passwd`

Edit:

lastlog -u

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
m21p37           pts/32   XX.XXX.XX.XXX    Tue May 17 19:31:38 +0200 2022
```

/etc/passwd

```
m21p37:x:7713:113:Name Surname:/home/students/m21p37:/bin/bash
```

What I get currently from my code:

```
m21p37  Name Surname        Username         Port     From             Latest
```

What I need:

```
m21p37  Name Surname        Tue May 17 19:31:38 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ name='m21p37'
$ awk -v name="$name" -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{t=$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8; next} $1==name{print $1, $5, t}' <(lastlog -u "$name") FS=':' /etc/passwd
m21p37  Name Surname    Tue May 17 19:31:38 +0200
```